# How to solve resource region dependency issue in Terraform

Tags: jenkins, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

For example: I have two separate modules, module-us-east-1, module-us-west-2. Now the consecutivity of running is module-us-east-1 then module-us-west-2 in the same Jenkins Pipeline. But module-us-east-1 will need some resources which will be created by module-us-west-2 abviously both modules will create resource in different regions.

Any hints on how this can be accomplished? :/

Comment: This sounds very complex. Can you provide a [mcve] that shows what you're trying to do and the issue at all please? There's quite possibly a few good answers (the two that jump out at me is either to split the execution so you don't apply everything in one go and reduce the blast radius and complexity or to potentially pass dependency references between the modules) but it's hard to tell exactly what you'd need from this little information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [aws_region data resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/region). It will pull in the current region that you are running in, so you can use the same module for both.

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}
```

Then you can template in the region when you need it:

```
"arn:aws:logs:${data.aws_region.current.name}:1234567890:log-group:*"
```

Edit:

You need four modules. Two modules, one for each region with interdependencies, is a circular dependency graph and will break.

Split the modules into shared and private resources, creating a shared and private module for each. Then use data resources to import
the shared resources into the private modules.

Comment: This doesn't answer the "module-us-east-1 will need some resources which will be created by module-us-west-2" part yet.

Comment: @Grzegorz Oledzki Looks like the question was more complicated than it looked like. Edited.

Comment: yes, you are right. Task it is a little bit tricky.

Comment: @setup you can also use `output` https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html  to pass the resources created in one module to another. that way there will be some dependency going on.

Comment: long short/story, somehow to solve this I separated each resources creation in different separated modules from each other.